# How to restore the file access time after extracting from archive

Tags: linux, backup, ntfs, tar, archiving

Is it possible under Linux to restore the file access time to that of the original file after extracting files from an archive created with tar on NTFS file system?

tar does not restore the access time even on "native" Linux file systems, so on Linux file systems I use the pax for extracting archives, which restores the access time. But on NTFS pax doesn't restore the access time. Is there a way to extract 'tar.gz' archives on NTFS file systems with restoring the original access time to the extracted files?

Comment: The access time on a file is so volatile that I cannot see why you would need to preserve it: surely what is important is the modification time, which **tar** preserves. I would expect the access time on all files to be the time when **tar** created the archive, so I guess you could use **touch** to recreate this from the modification time of the archive. The creation time will be when the **tar** extract was made, just as it is set on any copy of a file, which of course a **tar** extract is.

Comment: @AFH pax, actaully, restores the access time of the original file quite good, after extracting from an archive created with tar (or with the pax, of course). I'm using the access time to find the files and packages which are not used for a long time and to decide whether they can be moved to archive or removed for freeing disk space.

Answer (score 0):

You have to preserve the access time with tar at the moment you create your archive, option --atime-preserve

EDIT: This only preserves the access time on the original file because when tar reads files, it updates atime! You are right...

There doesn't seem to be a possibility to do this. If you need to preserve your atime, you can always use dd instead of tar, but that won't help you much on NTFS I suppose.

Comment: I'm using this tar's option, but it doesn't help. It seems to cause only preserving the original file's time.